# Bluetooth Headphones Quiet (Bose Quietcomort 35)

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, xps

I have the Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition, and when I connect my Bose Quietcomfort 35 via bluetooth they are quiet.

Any idea how I will get these to play at a normal volume?

Comment: What profile is it connected in? A2DP or HSP?

Comment: How do I figure this out? I'm fairly new to Ubuntu.

Comment: In Settings->Sound, there will be a list of output devices, one of which should be these headphones. When you select it, the pane will show various settings (balance, test sound, etc.). There should be a drop down menu labelled "mode" or "profile" or similar.

Comment: Was listed under headphones.

Comment: so it works now?